# How to do Ledger cutomisation under group Sundry Debtors through tdl

Tags: php

I want to add a custom field in Ledger under group Sundry Debtors by using Tally Definition Language(tdl). The following i coded ......

[#Part    :  LED Other Details]
    Add: Lines: IsFavorite

[Line : IsFavorite]
Fields : Medium prompt, IsFavorite
Local :field : Medium prompt :Set as : ” IsFavorite ”

;;;;fields;;;;
[Field : IsFavorite]
Use : Logical Field
;Use : Name Field
Storage : IsFavorite
Set as: No

[System : UDF]
;IsFavorite : String : 1001
IsFavorite : Logical: 1001

but by this the isFavourite field is added in all ledgers i want to display this field in only Ledgers which comes under Sundry Debtors group

I am using Tally.ERP9 and Tally.developer9

Answer (score -1):

you can add option part where you can add line as given below

```
[#Part : LED Other Details] 
   Option : CustomeLEDOtherDetailsPrt : $$IsGroupSundryDebtors:$Parent
[!Part : CustomeLEDOtherDetailsPrt]
     Add: Lines: IsFavorite
```

all other info will be same